# Insert Data from MySQL to Zoho Reports with the Upload Tool

Tags: mysql, zoho

I have a problem with the Zoho Reports upload tool. I have installed it on my server and in Terminal I want to run the sh script like this:

```
sh UploadFromDB.sh <username> <password>
```

When I run it I get the following error:

> UploadFromDB.sh: line 20: syntax error: unexpected end of file
>   (expecting "then")

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Can u post your sh file here ?